# Invalid SAML response received: Invalid user attributes phoneNumbers - Cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, saml

After successfull login from microsoft website it throws **Invalid SAML response received** in the network tab.

[image]

**Azure attributes mapping**

[image]

**Cognito attributes mapping**

[image]

Below is my React.js Code which uses Amplify library (aws-amplify ver 4.3.8)

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        userPoolWebClientId: 'xyz',
        userPoolId: 'xyz',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        oauth: {
            domain: 'xyz.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
            scope: ['aws.cognito.signin.user.admin', 'email', 'openid', 'profile', 'phone'],
            redirectSignIn: 'https://stdev.net/',
            responseType: 'CODE'
        }
    }
});


Auth.federatedSignIn({ customProvider: 'AzureProviderId' });
```